# Configurar helenium en intellij

Tags: java, selenium, test-ng

Instale el plugin de Helenium en intellij pero al ejecutarlo no me funciona, no me esta refactorizando la automatizacion me sale "No hay resultados de curación disponibles", ya agregue la dependencia de helenium la 3.2.1 la configuracion con la base de datos,el archivo healeniumproperties, pero no se que me pueda estar faltando para que que no me funcione

Comment: Estimado le recomiendo, usar gradle o maven como gestor dependencias, luego la agrega en el builde.gradle o pom.xml y ya con eso le deberia descargar la libreria en su proyecto. Si tiene problemas para descargar aun teniendo gradle o maven validar conexion a internet y no estar conectado alguna vpn.